# Square matrix length of path in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a square connection truth matrix between units. It shows which units are connected to each other.
E.g.

```
[[False, False, True], # 1
 [False, False, True], # 2
 [True, True, False]]  # 3
```

Can be interpreted as:

- 1 is not connected to itself, neither to 2, and it is connected to 3
- 2 is not connected to 1, neither to itself, and it is connected to 3
- 3 is connected to 1, 3 is connected to 2, but it is not connected to self

When I'd want to find length of the path for all units, the result would be:

```
distances = [[0, 2, 1], 
             [2, 0, 1],
             [1, 1, 0]]
```

It's a lack of algorithm skills that I cannot figure this out...

Note that I know shortest path evaluations, but I'd need this kind of structure since then it will be made easy to do further operations.

For example, later I might say, I want to know the longest distance of the shortest distances, where I can start from units 5,7,10 to units 15,16,17.

```
np.max(np.min(distances[np.array([5,6,7])][:, np.array([15,16,17])], 1))
```

The application might be in a game of Risk, where you would want to capture all regions belonging to a bonus, starting from all your owned regions. It would give a lower bound in terms of number of turns needed to reach all the regions in the bonus (ignoring whether or not you're able to capture in terms of troops). In the context of this simple example:

```
froms = np.array([1,2])
tos = np.array([0,1])
np.max(np.min(distances[froms][:, tos], 1))
1
```

Comment: Dude, seriously, too broad? I gave an input example and an output example?

Comment: You want to know distances? What do you mean by length of path? The graph can have cycles.

Comment: @simonzack Yea, the minimum distance (length of the path, used as synonym) from each unit to each unit.

Comment: @moose It's not my closevote/downvote. Like you said, I wouldn't answer the question if I close-voted it.

Comment: @simonzack Oh, sorry, I thought you wrote a similar comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

In[1]:

```
scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall(np.matrix(
    [[False, False, True],
     [False, False, True],
     [True, True, False]]
).astype(int))
```

Out[1]:

```
array([[ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: That's amazing really... How did you guys even find that?

Comment: Learnt this in undergrad CS, but can't always remember the name, a quick google brought it up.

Comment: Wish I had (under)grad in CS, would be so useful these days.... How did you google for it though? I'd have no idea how to find it

Comment: @PascalvKooten I think mine was more fun than useful :) An algorithms book would cover this btw, you can pick one up and give it a quick read.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "[Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)".

```
def floyd_warshall(W):
    n = len(W)
    D = {x: None for x in range(n)}
    D[0] = W
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        D[k] = list(D[k-1])
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                D[k][i][j] = min(D[k-1][i][j], D[k-1][i][k-1] + D[k-1][k-1][j])
    return D[n]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    INF = float('inf')
    W = [[0, 1, INF, INF],
         [INF, 0, 3, 1],
         [INF, INF, 0, 8],
         [INF, 2, INF, 0]]
    print(floyd_warshall(W))
```

For your case, the matrix would be

```
    W = [[0, INF, 1],
         [INF, 0, 1],
         [1, 1, 0]]
```

This is a distance matrix. Floyd-Warshall calculates a new distance matrix with the minimum distance. So some values will be the same (e.g. 0 values) and others will be reduced to the minimum number.

There seems to be also a SciPy implementation: [`cipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall.html#scipy-sparse-csgraph-floyd-warshall)

Comment: With my input, it just returns itself?

Comment: I've just extended my answer. Your input has to be transformed to a distance matrix.

Comment: @PascalvKooten It retruns itself, because `False` is converted to `0`. You cannot get a distance below zero. This is the reason why you have to transform the input.